# Codeigniter cart goes empty on bulk items

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for my e-commerce website, Whenever I insert approx 20 or more items in cart, cart automatically empties on page refresh.

As concern to previous questions, i am already using it in database level. 
`$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;`

Can try this, on a high reach, it empties on refresh

```
for($i = 1; $i < 500; $i++) {
   $this->cart->insert(array(
            'id' => $i,
            'qty' => 1,
            'price' => 1,
            'name' => "Test"
    ));
}
```

Comment: I think you should save your cart values in session and use as your wish

Comment: `Whenever I insert more than 20 items in a cart, cart automatically empties on page refresh. ` what happen if there are less than 20 items and you refresh the page?

Comment: Not related to time session?

Comment: Which version you are using CI 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan version is 3

Comment: @Anant question edited, approx on this

Answer (score 0):

can change that's code?

```
foreach ($items as $item){  
   $this->cart->insert(array(  
            'id' => $item['id'],  
            'qty' => $item['qty'],  
            'price' =>$item['price'],  
            'name' => "Test"  
    ));  
}
```

Comment: Thats not something i need, cart goes empty on bulk insert